# Wiki.js GraphQL: create page example

Tags: api, graphql, wiki.js

I'm totally new at GraphQL and I don't understand how to compose a `PageMutation` `create` call for Wiki.js. Their GraphQL playground is available on the [public docs](https://docs.requarks.io/graphql). The schema for creation is:

```
type PageMutation {
  create(
    content: String!
    description: String!
    editor: String!
    isPublished: Boolean!
    isPrivate: Boolean!
    locale: String!
    path: String!
    publishEndDate: Date
    publishStartDate: Date
    scriptCss: String
    scriptJs: String
    tags: [String]!
    title: String!
  ): PageResponse
```

In the GraphQL docs pages they say mutation parameters should be declared as *input* ones, but this one isn't. Also, I've seen no description for this kind of *structure* (object in object?), and I don't see how to use it.

Hints welcome.
Thanks

Comment: play with playground, it hints possible code lines ... create hardcoded mutation then parametrize it using query variables ... not much different than normal, simple, flat graphql schema

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So here's the example for a page creation without variables, just the mutation itself:

```json
mutation Page {
  pages {
    create (content:"contenuto", description:"descrizione", editor: "code", isPublished: true, isPrivate: false, locale: "it", path:"/", tags: ["tag1", "tag2"], title:"titolo") {
      responseResult {
        succeeded,
        errorCode,
        slug,
        message
      },
      page {
        id,
        path,
        title
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Details on [GraphQL docs](https://graphql.org/learn/schema/#the-query-and-mutation-types).

Here's an example with variables:

```json
mutation Page ($content: String!, $descrizione: String!, $editor:String!, $isPublished:Boolean!, $isPrivate:Boolean!, $locale:String!, $path:String!,$tags:[String]!, $title:String!) {
  pages {
    create (content:$content, description:$descrizione, editor: $editor, isPublished: $isPublished, isPrivate: $isPrivate, locale: $locale, path:$path, tags: $tags, title:$title) {
      responseResult {
        succeeded,
        errorCode,
        slug,
        message
      },
      page {
        id,
        path,
        title
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Query variables:

```json
{
  "content": "contenuto", 
  "descrizione":"descrizione", 
  "editor": "code", 
  "isPublished": true, 
  "isPrivate": false, 
  "locale": "it", 
  "path":"/pagina01", 
  "tags": ["tag1", "tag2"], 
  "title":"titolo"
}
```